# county borders with US county names

Tags: usa, geospatial, county

So I downloaded QGIS and the 2014 TIGER/Line Shapefiles for US counties from ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2014/COUNTY/

When I open the shapefiles up in QGIS I don't see any of the county names. Does the TIGER data simply not include county names or is there some option in QGIS that I'm just unaware of?

Comment: you can get a sense of extracting various attributes from shapefiles from this r code  https://github.com/davidbrae/swmap/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The data is in the Shapefile and the packaged `dbf` file. In QGIS, you can use the `Attribute Table` or `Identify Feature` tools to expose these attributes. Animated GIF below here: [http://i.imgur.com/lSXp4Qr.gif](https://i.imgur.com/lSXp4Qr.gif)

Answer (score 0):

Skram has a good answer. I would add that if you are simply trying to label your counties, watch this GIF: [Add Labels](http://gyazo.com/1359ba433c4f488f455146b177ecb5b7)